# Python open login required API https protocol

Tags: python, http

I am trying to access an API with the following characteristics:

protocol：https

method：“GET”

url：“https://api.wmcloud.com/data/v1//api/equity/getEqu.json?field=&listStatusCD=&secID=&ticker=&equTypeCD=A 
header：“Authorization: Bearer <token>”

So if I just open the url, I can see all the data there. My code to access it on the other hand does not work. My code is:

```
import httplib
httpClient = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.wmcloud.com', '443',timeout=60)
url = 'https://api.wmcloud.com/data/v1//api/equity/getEqu.json?field=&listStatusCD=&secID=&ticker=&equTypeCD=A'
token='ae8820c8eb8ccd418dd8141b4c685d2d208c58a564a9fd2c22f8c95ac6a2ef23'   
alldata = httpClient.request('GET', url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + token})
```

It returns None when print alldata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@yorah has already found the root cause of the problem: in order to send HTTP request, `getresponse()` needs to be invoked.

As OP uses Python 2 and @yorah's code is in Python 3, which may not work in OP's environment, I'd like to fix and refactor the solution in Python 2 as below:

```
import httplib, urllib, json
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.wmcloud.com", 443, timeout=60)
token = "ae8820c8eb8ccd418dd8141b4c685d2d208c58a564a9fd2c22f8c95ac6a2ef23"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}
params = urllib.urlencode({"listStatusCD": "L", "secID": "000001.XSHE", "ticker":"000001", "equTypeCD": "A"})
conn.request("GET", "/data/v1/api/equity/getEqu.json?" + params, "", headers)
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print r1.status, r1.reason
result = json.load(r1)
print len(result['data'])  # Expect: 1
```

Please note it takes some time to load the response data.

For related document in Python 2, please refer to https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/httplib.html

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It seems to be working.
However, when I tried to pass in more parameters, it does not seem to affect anything.
I changed the parameters to:
 `params = urllib.urlencode({"field": "&","listStatusCD": "L","secID": "000001.XSHE","ticker":"000001","equTypeCD":"A"})` as per the website, but the output is still the whole population.
Interestingly, when print this parameter I find the "ticker" is always in front of "secID" while in the code it is after.
Output:`field=%26&listStatusCD=L&ticker=000001&secID=000001.XSHE&equTypeCD=A`

Comment: @Liam The parameter filter does not work because it should be included in URL, not `body`. I've updated my answer, please check.

Comment: The parameter sequence does not matter. Also, as there is no `field` parameter value, it should not be included in `params` -- `&` is the character to separate multiple parameters in URL, it is not part of parameter value.

Comment: I used your code, and it doesn't work. It spells out a bunch of error. The previous code still works with the problem of params not doing anything.
Output error:
TypeError: unhashable type

Comment: @Liam hmmm...I'm using Python 2.6 and it works well. Which Python version are you using?

Comment: I am also using Python 2.7 and the problem seems to be json.load vs json.loads....

Comment: @Liam `json.load()` expect `fp` (file/stream object itself), while `json.loads()` expect string or buffer (the data). As `conn.getresponse()` returns an `HTTPResponse` instance, `json.load()` should be the right choice. For my code, did you change `json.load()` to `json.loads()` and then it works? That would be pretty weird...

Comment: load() was the right choice, your code works. I was using loads hence the error.

Comment: @Liam Glad to hear that your problem is solved. Please mark yorah or my answer as accepted, so that people visiting this page will know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html

---

After sending the `request`, you need to also:

- Get the response
- Read the response (and decode it)

The following should do what you want:

```
import httplib
httpClient = http.client.HTTPSConnection('api.wmcloud.com', '443', timeout=60)
url = 'https://api.wmcloud.com/data/v1//api/equity/getEqu.json?field=&listStatusCD=&secID=&ticker=&equTypeCD=A'
token='ae8820c8eb8ccd418dd8141b4c685d2d208c58a564a9fd2c22f8c95ac6a2ef23'
httpClient.request('GET', url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token})

alldata = httpClient.getresponse()

print(alldata.read().decode())
```